# Video Format large screen wrong

Tags: ffmpeg, video

we have problems with some videos beeing played in media-player.
media-player reads the video size wrong.
The videos are displayed too large, say for large screen like today.
But the videos are for recent screens sizes like in former tvs.
So the effect is, that we have strange wide faces and extremely long cars,
very unnaturally.

My questions is, which parameter tells media-player this wrong format
and how can we correct this in the video.

Thanks lot for assistance.

cheers mike

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide the output of `ffprobe` (a _ffmpeg_ companion program) for a video that shows up incorrectly (this is text, so please add it as text) and if possible also a screenshot. Please clarify which media player software you are using. Is it Windows Media Player?

Comment: thanks for your responses.
unfortunately i'm completely new for ffprobe.
yes it's windows media player we use.
please tell me the commandline to get the output of ffprobe.
thanks for assistance

Comment: Just open a Command Prompt window and run `"C:\path\to\ffprobe.exe" "C:\path\to\video.avi"`.

Comment: Please add the output, in its entirety, to your question. Put it in a code block so it can have the original Command Prompt formatting.

Comment: …meaning, [edit the question](https://superuser.com/posts/1747335/edit).

Comment: {Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'I:\test.mp4': Metadata: major_brand : isom minor_version : 1 compatible_brands: mp42iso2avc1isom creation_time : 2020-09-22T15:54:51.000000Z Duration: 00:25:34.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8227 kb/s Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 8028 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 12 800 tbn (default)}

Comment: As far as I understand DAR 16:9 should be changed to DAR 4:3.
How do i manage this?
thanks

Comment: You may use `setsar` filter: Example: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "setsar=3/4"  output.mp4`. A better way (for H.264 codec), without re-encoding, use `h264_metadata` bitstream filter. Example: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=sample_aspect_ratio=0.75 output.mp4`

Comment: thanks both commands work exellent.
but how do i get these values?
for DAR 4/3 (your examples)
or DAR 16/9 (where i came from)
How to calculate?
Thanks for details.
Cheers mike